# Hat rendering bug in profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, winter-bash-2012

It has done this a few times now. Do you see the `i` being drawn on top of my hat?

[image]

It doesn't do this every time but this is the second time now it has looked bugged or wrong. Is it browser bug? Anyone else have the problem?

Comment: Huh. Good eyes you have.

Comment: other time was `m` so it was easier to see. i think its the edges?

Comment: For it to be deemed a browser bug we need to know what browser you saw this in :P

Comment: It might help if you stick that hat back on yourself as well.  I can't see it on my own profile or @Yannis'.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The fix is available in the Jan 5 drop

Comment: [har har har](http://instantrimshot.com/) ;)